# Getting unexpected results when using macros with arguments

Tags: c, macros, swap, conditional-operator, preprocessor-directive

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define big(a, b) a > b ? a : b
#define swap(a, b) temp = a; a = b; b = temp;

int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 5, temp = 0;
    if ((3 + big(a, b)) > b)
        swap(a, b);
    printf("%d %d", a, b);
}
```

Above code was given in a multiple choice question.
I expected the answer to be 5 3. On running the code, output comes out to be 5  0. I've tried to make sense of this but my efforts have gone in vain. What's the working of this code?

Comment: In C++ use of [macros are considered a bad practice](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-macros2)

Comment: Original question didn't have parenthesis either. I wanted to know how that statement is altering the program. @YSC

Comment: C or C++? The later discourages macros for the exact same type of problems. Proper answer depends on the language.

Comment: Your macro `swap` is sensitive to statements which are using own scopes like `if` `while`. Here is visualization of the problem: https://cppinsights.io/s/d89e8426

Comment: @YSC It's not a typo in the OP's code.  The question is asking why the crappy code copied from elsewhere produced the results posted.  There are likely many dupe candidates, though.

Comment: Expand the macros by hand and see what the code really looks like. (And don't be fooled by how the `swap` expands to one line.)

Comment: @Red.Wave I'm sorry for confusion. Its for C

Comment: I voted for reopening as this is not a "typo problem".

Comment: Link https://cppinsights.io/s/d89e8426 I've provided should explain everything. There are at least two bugs introduced by use of this macros.

Comment: @Kanishk OK. Now follow the tips given above on `swap` macro; that's a major issue. `big` is not totally fine either, but this sample has problems with `swap`.

Comment: Yeah, that `swap()` macro is stupendously bad.  For those wondering why, look deeply into what `if (???) swap(a,b);` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expand the macros in the code and you will get

```
int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 5, temp = 0;
    if ((3 + a > b ? a : b ) > b)
        temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;    
    printf("%d %d", a, b);
}
```

As the first expression `3 + a` in the conditional operator is equal to `6` then the result of the conditional operator is the value of `a` that is less than `b`.

So the condition of the if statement evaluates to logical false and the statement

```
temp = a;
```

is skipped.

As a result `a` will be equal to `5` and `b` will be equal to `0`.

You need to use parentheses. For example

```
#define big(a, b) ( ( a ) > ( b ) ? ( a ) : ( b ) )
#define swap(a, b) do { temp = ( a ); ( a ) = ( b ); ( b ) = temp; } while ( 0 )
```

Answer (score 2):

`gcc -E` ([preprocessing only](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html)) renders the following output:

```
int main() {
    int a = 3, b = 5, temp = 0;
    if ((3 + a > b ? a : b) > b)
        temp = a; a = b; b = temp;;
    printf("%d %d", a, b);
}
```

From this we can see that the body of the `if` statement is comprised only of the first expression statement (`temp = a;`), terminating with the first semi-colon.

`a = b; b = temp;;` fall outside the `if` body, to be unconditionally executed. Note the extra semi-colon as well.

---

The typical pattern to have multiple expression statements contained in a macro is to make use of `do { ... } while (0)`, which groups the statements to a new block scope, and allows the use of a trailing semi-colon to be consistent.

The other thing to do is to aggressively parenthesize macro arguments, and often entire macros, to ensure operator precedence remains as consistent as possible.

Note that `swap` relying on an implicit `temp` variable to be defined is a code smell. One possibility for a better approach would be to pass the type instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define big(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define swap(type, a, b) do { type temp = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = temp; } while (0)

int main(void)
{
    int a = 3, b = 5;

    if ((3 + big(a, b)) > b)
        swap(int, a, b);

    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

Preprocessor output:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 3, b = 5;

    if ((3 + (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))) > b)
        do { int temp = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = temp; } while (0);

    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

Program output:

```
5 3
```

An issue not addressed by this example is that both these macros evaluate their arguments more than once, something that becomes tricky when side effects are involved (e.g., `macro(func(x++), y--)`).

See also: [GCC CPP - 3.10.4 Duplication of Side Effects](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Duplication-of-Side-Effects.html)

Comment: C23's [`typeof`](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#6.7.2.5) would be useful in a simpler `swap()` macro.  (Or is it going to be C24...)